# Zip folder recursively, save for a given sub folder (Linux)

Tags: linux, zip, directory

In Linux zip, is it possible to zip a folder recursively except for a given sub-path?

For instance, to zip 'base_folder' and all its sub folders except 'base_folder/sub_folder'.

Is it possible?
And if so, how?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`zip -r base_folder.zip base_folder -x base_folder/sub_folder/\* base_folder/another_sub_folder/\*`

(I have incorporated the improved information from your experience that you have kindly offered in your comment.)

For more information: `man zip`

Comment: zip -r zip_file.zip base_folder -x 'base_folder/first_folder_to_skip/*' 'base_folder/second_folder_to_skip/*'

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tar` with `--exclude`, and use the `-z` option to gzip the output tar file.

Answer (score 1):

find the files, exclude the folder, xargs the remaining files to tar or zip or whatever:

```
find /in/your/dir | grep -v 'name_of_dir_to_be_excluded' | xargs tar jcvf nameOfArchive.tar.bz2
```